# MTL file along with OBJ file for displaying 3D models in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, .obj, mtls, mtl-file

I followed the example from [p5.js Reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadModel)
It contains an example of how to load an OBJ file in JavaScript with p5.js:

```
//draw a spinning teapot
let teapot;

function preload() {
  // Load model with normalise parameter set to true
  teapot = loadModel('assets/teapot.obj', true);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 100, WEBGL);
  describe('Vertically rotating 3-d teapot with red, green and blue gradient.');
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  scale(0.4); // Scaled to make model fit into canvas
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  normalMaterial(); // For effect
  model(teapot);
}
```

Is there a way to load an MTL file which contains the material and texture information to replace the normalMaterial() function?

The texture() function doesn't work right for 3D objects.